# TEXMFHOME not present

Tags: texlive

I'm having some trouble with TeXLive.
I was using the 2013 version but I coulnd't install Beamer.
For this reason I uninstalled TeXLive 2013 and then I installed the 2014 version.

The problem is that there is no TEXMFHOME folder:
I changed the default from `~/texmf` to `~/.texmf` but neither of them exists.
How can I fix it?

edit: My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 . I wanted to install Beamer because I
selected medium installation instead of full.

Comment: `mkdir $HOME/texmf` in a terminal for example? Was such a folder present before the update?

Comment: The essential information about your operating system is missing.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install `beamer` unless you seclected a reduced scheme when installing TeX Live. (That is, you did not install the default `full` scheme.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, the first time I installed TexLive 2013 I am quite sure it was present (and I wanted to hide that folder).
Then, for other reason, I uninstalled everything and reinstalled from scratch. From that moment it wasn't present anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing TeX Live never creates `TEXMFHOME` directories in the users' homes. Would you trust an installer program that tampers with users' personal data? I wouldn't.

If you have a GNU/Linux system, then just do

```
cd
mkdir ~/texmf
```

from a terminal window and create the necessary tree structure below it. If you are running MacTeX, then you need

```
mkdir ~/Library/texmf
```

but directly installing TeX Live on Mac OS X will need `~/texmf` unless a different setting is defined in `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf`.

By the way, using `TEXMFHOME` for `beamer` is quite dubious, as it's possible to install `beamer` in the main tree. How to install it depends on the flavor of TeX Live you have installed. If it is the TUG vanilla TeX Live, then `beamer` is in `collection-latexrecommended`.

Comment: In `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf` I added the line `TEXHOME = ~/.texmf`.
Anyway, do you mean that Beamer doesn't require that folder in order to be installed?

Comment: @dario_romagnoli Of course it doesn't need it. The line `TEXHOME=~/.texmf` will do nothing, as `TEXHOME` is not a recognized variable.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I meant `TEXMFHOME`

In any case I installed Beamer.
I think I just need to understand better how TDS works.

Answer (score 3):

run in a terminal:

```
voss@shania:~/ConTeXt> kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/voss/texmf
```

or

```
voss@shania:~/ConTeXt> kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

it shows you the current setting.

Inside the `$TEXMFHOME` and `$TEXMFLOCAL` you should have a directory structure as explained in  TDS: http://www.tug.org/tetex/html/tds/tds_toc.html#SEC23

For example: A local style file should be in `~/texmf/tex/latex/myStyle/`

However, why do you want to install Beamer? It is already present.